# Facebook has blocked logins for my Meteor app because I'm not using a native SDK. How to resolve?

Tags: facebook, meteor, authentication

I manage a few Meteor-based apps that use the Facebook login functionality provided through `accounts-facebook`.

For one app, a week ago, Facebook emailed me saying this app was in violation of their Platform Policy, and that I had to respond to the email to prevent logins from being shut down within a week. Specifically this was the offensive clause:

> Platform Policy 8.2: Native iOS and Android apps that implement
>   Facebook Login must use our official SDKs for Login.

I immediately responded, but (of course?) got no response from Facebook. And, yesterday, I got another email saying Facebook logins have been blocked for this app.

I updated to the latest version of `accounts-facebook`, appealed the block, and got a response:

> We have reviewed your iOS and Android apps and they are still in
>   violation of the Platform Policy 8.2: Native iOS and Android apps that
>   implement Facebook Login must use our official SDKs for Login.

So, does this mean that all Meteor apps can get their Facebook login restricted at any time?

How to resolve this?

Today, Facebook went further, telling me that:

> Your app has been restricted for creating a negative user experience
>   that is in violation of our Platform Policies.
>
> Your app cannot be installed by new users.

What are they smoking?

But, whatever they are smoking, how do I resolve this?

I've sent them an email, twice, explaining that, like tens of thousands of others, I'm using the off-the-shelf Meteor package for allowing Facebook logins to my Meteor app. But, all I get back are canned responses that don't respond to my bafflement.

Comment: They want you to write a real native app, so do it, you will end up with better skills and your customers will have a better experience. It's that hard really, just do it. Otherwise you have to drop Facebook from your app. You also can contact Meteor community.

Comment: Just because you use the off-the-shelf Meteor package doesn't mean it meets Facebooks policies. They said that you need to use Facebook official SDK. If you do that through a third party library or by your self doesn't matter.